# Windows forms register dependencies using Unity

Tags: c#, winforms, unity-container

Where do I setup my container and register all my dependencies for a WinForm app? Do I setup the container on every form or is there a common place I can do it (like the Main function)? Also, is there a bootstrap for WinForms apps?
I am new to Unity and trying to learn it.

Comment: Unity3D is that what we're tlaking about?

Comment: @AmitApollo: nope, he talks about Unity, an IoC container.

Answer (score 0):

You register your dependencies in a Composition Root which would be the Main in a WinForms app. Setting up a new container in every form takes you nowhere.

I am not sure if a Prism Bootstrapper works in a console app but at least you should give it a try.

Comment: If I set it up in the CR how do I access the container in my forms? Do i need to create a singleton to hold the container?